# How to add the feature to display video formats with the resolution of user's choice to download

Tags: python, html, django, youtube, pytube

The below code is in views.py .I want to take a variable from the user instead of the '360p' after user pastes the video link. Is there a way to show how to get the resolution from the user.I have to take input from the user.
The full code looks something like the below webpage
https://www.hexascholars.com/code-snippet/youtube-video-download-using-django-and-python/

````
def get_download(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        if(request.GET.get('url')):
            url = request.GET['url']
            try:
                yt = YouTube(url)
                title = yt.title
                stream = yt.streams.filter(res='360p').first()
                path = download_path()
                stream.download(path)
                message = "Download Complete!"
                video = Video()```
````

Comment: Do you want to display a list of possible resolutions to the user from which he can pick one?

Comment: Yes exactly i want that . The possibile resolutions are displayed and user has an option to choose one

Comment: pytube is no longer maintained, consider using pytube3 instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do it the "plain vanilla" way, i.e. without using django Forms you can just add a grup of radio buttons or a select to the form in your html, e.g.

```
<form method="GET" action="/your/url/">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Enter Youtube URL</label>
        <input type="url" class="form-control" required="required" name="link">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Resolution</label>
        <fieldset>
            <input type="radio" name="res" id="res1" value="360p">
            <label for="res1">360p</label>
            <input type="radio" name="res" id="res2" value="720p">
            <label for="res1">720p</label>
        </fieldset>

    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="save btn btn-success">Download</button>
</form>
```

In your view you can fetch the parameter the same way you are getting the url:

```
res = request.GET.get('res')
```

and then use "res" instead of your hard-coded string.

Comment: Should i connect it in the URLs.py too

Comment: You fetch the resolution in your ```get_download``` view. I suppose this is already in your ```urls.py```, so you do not need an additional one.

Comment: Thank u very much Sir.Highly obliged and lots of Gratitude